# Why is there electrolyte soaked paper in an electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: capacitance, electrolytic-capacitor

1. I know that the soaked paper spacer is there to protect oxide layer but how does it protect it and from whom does it protect it?
2. Why does the paper spacer need to be soaked in electrolyte and what happens if we replace the paper with a plastic film (which cannot be soaked in electrolyte?)
3. If I change the design a little bit and place two paper spacers and provide a little gap (vacuum) between two paper spacers then will there be an electric field between them? (This is a thought experiment, I was curious to know what if, so please neglect that capacitance value decreases if we generate the gap, I just wanted to know that will there be electric field between two paper space.)

Comment: 3) should probably be asked as a separate question; it's not really related to the other two.

Comment: Electrolyte is one of electrodes. Second the aluminum foil. Oxide layer is insulator.

Comment: A liquid electrolyte will not maintain the physical separation, so the paper is there to be the physical separator.

Comment: The electrolyte makes it an electrolytic capacitor. If you change that to a plastic film, it will be a plastic film capacitor.

Comment: Did I not answer your question?

Comment: There are two fundamental and different material properties. Dielectrics which are insulators and conductors which are not insulators.   @user263983 posted a comment that breaks these laws of material physics

Answer (score 3):

In an electrolytic capacitor, the oxide layer forms only between the positive plate and the electrolyte.  It can be super-thin, even with 1930's manufacturing techniques, because it is formed chemically rather than mechanically.  It is the thinness of this layer that gives electrolytic capacitors their very high capacitance to size ratio.

In an *aluminum* electrolytic capacitor*, the aluminum on the negative side is *not* insulated from the electrolyte**.  This means that the *negative* plate is *not* just the aluminum part -- the actual working part of the negative plate is the electrolyte itself.  This is to some extent why electrolytics tend to have high series resistance, and why they stop working when they dry out***.

So:

> I know that the soaked paper spacer is there to protect oxide layer but how does it protect it and from whom does it protect it?

Your "knowledge" is, if not wrong, then not in the center of the target.  The paper spacer is there to separate the positive from the negative plates so that the oxide layer *can* form.  I suppose that if you stay in that head space then "from whom does it protect it" would be answered by "from the aluminum sheet in the negative plate"

> Why does the paper spacer need to be soaked in electrolyte and what happens if we replace the paper with a plastic film (which cannot be soaked in electrolyte?)

Then you would just have a paper capacitor (they are, or were, a thing, occupying the same niche in electronics as film caps do today).  The paper would be the dielectric, and as a consequence the dielectric layer would be much, much thicker and the capacitance would be lower.

> If I change the design a little bit and place two paper spacers and provide a little gap (vacuum) between two paper spacers then will there be an electric field between them? (This is a thought experiment, I was curious to know what if, so please neglect that capacitance value decreases if we generate the gap, I just wanted to know that will there be electric field between two paper space.)

There would be an electric field going from one aluminum plate to the other, through both pieces of paper and the vacuum.  The paper would only change the characteristics of the field as a consequence of its permittivity.  You'd basically have a paper-vacuum-paper cap.

(Note that a vacuum cap is a thing, too -- search on "vacuum cap".  They're used in high-power radio circuits; they have a lower breakdown voltage for their size than an air-dielectric cap, they don't produce ozone, and their characteristics don't change with humidity or altitude).

* And maybe all of them -- I only know for sure about aluminum electrolytics.

** In fact [you can make electrolytics in a jar](https://rimstar.org/science_electronics_projects/make_electrolytic_capacitor.htm), and in further fact, really early radio technology (like, 1910's) use home-made electrolytics with commercial borax, fruit jars, and scrap aluminum sheet.

*** And, further, why they have lower temperature ratings than semiconductors, and why they have finite lifespans.

Comment: For your one-asterisk footnote: This is true of standard aluminum electrolytics, but by oxidizing both plates you can make a non-polar aluminum electrolytic, which are commercially available though perhaps less so now with MLCCs continuing to get cheaper. I'm almost certain it's also true of aluminum-polymer and solid tantalum electrolytics, but I don't know about supercapacitors or niobium electrolytics.

Comment: I know that non-polars are available, but not how they're made.  Now I know a _little_ bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I think a heated discussion here is mostly due to some semantic differences in describing mechanical construction of the capacitors, rather than their functionality. I'll try to explain why @TimWescott and @user263983 were correct and lets see if we can find a consensus.

I won't be talking about laws of physics, because frankly, I don't know much. And I will be using only one, rather respectable [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor), because it is usually very careful with terminology, unlike manufacturing papers focused on production.

So, what is a capacitor?

> Most capacitors contain at least two electrical conductors often in
> the form of metallic plates or **surfaces** separated by a dielectric
> medium. A conductor may be a foil, thin film, sintered bead of metal,
> or an **electrolyte**.

I emphasized "surface" here, because the thickness of the conductor is mostly irrelevant for the capacitance, which is defined only by permittivity of the dielectric, surface area, and a distance between plates (thickness of dielectric).
Here are some quotes to supplement this:

> the charge on each plate will be spread evenly in a **surface charge**
> layer of constant charge density

And from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_charge):

> According to Gauss’s law ... the entirety of the charge of the
> conductor resides on the surface.

*From the above, it wouldn't be a stretch to say that the capacitor itself consists of two 2-dimensional surfaces and dielectric between them, the rest of it just electric terminals, housing and some insulation.*

Of course, most people do not think in physical abstractions, that is why we are calling entire electronic device "a capacitor", just as we call the leads of electrolytic capacitors a "cathode" and an "anode". Once again, the wikipedia [gets it right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types):

[image]

Note how the negative aluminum foil is called "**Cathode terminal**", rather than cathode. That is because in electrolytic capacitor the electrolyte IS a cathode, or rather a tiny boundary layer of it in contact with oxide dielectric. Therefore the negative foil does not play a role of capacitor plate. *The size of it and the thickness of the electrolyte-permeated paper do not affect the capacitance, only ESR.*

This is even more pronounced in tantalum electrolytic capacitors or aluminum capacitors with [solid manganese dioxide electrolytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_electrolytic_capacitor).

[image]

In these, there is no second aluminum foil at all. However there are two additional layers, graphite and silver, between electrolyte an a negative lead. Just as negative foil in aluminum capacitor, these are not cathodes but electrical connectors, or **terminals**. That was the whole point of the answers provided by @TimWescott and @user263983.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are exotic nano-size fabricated materials with non-homegenous properties., this answer does not pretend to cover quantum physics nor nanotube electrical material science. It is just the fundamental truth to electrolytic capacitors or e-caps.

E-caps have improved more than a hundred-fold in my lifetime as an engineer in 1974, by making a conductor surface 3D with sputtered oxide materials with 100 times the surface area per cross-sectional area and thus 1% of the ESR compared to a standard e-cap.

2nd answer from journal reference as some users are posting false statements, with upvotes , downvoting correct answers and generally being ignorant without references to justify above.

Physical Model of the Capacitor:

An aluminum electrolytic capacitor, illustrated in Fig. 2 consists of;

1. a cathode and anode made of aluminum foil,
2. a  separator (electrolytic) paper, electrolyte,
   3, and an aluminum oxide layer, which acts as the dielectric to the anode foil surface.

(NOTE MATERIALS ARE EITHER CONDUCTORS OR INSULATORS, Ideal materials cannot be both. T.S.  )

When in contact with the electrolyte, the oxide layer possesses excellent insulation properties in the forward direction. Etching the foil magnifies the effective surface area, allowing for high capacitance in a small volume.

Since the oxide layer has rectifying properties, a capacitor has polarity. If both the anode and cathode foils have an oxide layer, the capacitor is bipolar. In this paper, we analyze ‘non-solid’ aluminum electrolytic capacitors in which the electrolytic paper is impregnated with a liquid electrolyte.

Another type of aluminum electrolytic capacitor uses a solid electrolyte.

Journal References:

1. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241195108_Prognostic_Techniques_for_Capacitor_Degradation_and_Health_Monitoring

[image]

2. https://eepower.com/capacitor-guide/types/electrolytic-capacitor/#

[image]

3. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/how-to-select-the-right-aluminum-electrolytic-capacitor/
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMWVNcgOKA4
5. 

Comment: "materials are either conductors or insulators" is not quite true if you get to some weird things like topological insulators, which are highly conductive on the *surface* and highly insulative in the bulk, despite being the same material in both cases. But it is true, or at least a useful simplified model, of almost everything you'd encounter day to day.

Comment: @Hearth  Fundamental Physics agrees with me.  There are boundaries to materials. Your example is not homogeneous

Comment: The example has a boundary, yes, but it doesn't matter what's on the other side of that boundary as long as it isn't more of the topological insulator. You didn't say anything about the material having no boundary and thus occupying all space. Even so, there are other examples, like titanium nitride, which transitions from being a reasonably good insulator to a superconductor if you cool it below about 6 K.

Comment: @Hearth we are talking about consumer electronic capacitors with homogenous properties. There are only 3 homogenous natural electrical properties here RLC and L is not relevant.  We are not talking about esoteric bifurcated materials. So please do not distract newbie readers from the truth with exotic materials.  Similarilary metalized film has 2 distinct materials. metal on insulator film. Fundamentally at DC there are only 2 properties. Insulators and non-insulators. All insulators are dielectrics and all dielectrics are insulators including air and vacuum.

Comment: At the nano scale your example is still two materials, a conductor and a non-conductor or an insulator and a non-insulator or an insulator and a conductor.  These are just synonyms

Comment: There really is no basis for considering something to be two materials when it's a chemical compound, particularly when we're talking about quantum effects like superconductivity that rely on the crystal structure that you can't get with just one of the elements alone. My point is just that you can't make blanket statements like "all materials are either conductors or insulators" unless you qualify it as "to a first approximation" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Hearth this is a parking lot discussion. Interesting but irrelevant.  The material properties are distinct as the materials. They are not diffused or confused.. We are talking fundamentals and you are encouraging fundamental false understandings

Comment: From where I'm standing, it feels a lot more like you're the one at risk of encouraging misunderstandings.

Comment: @Hearth show me one phsyics or EE book or journal reference as I have to support your views,    You are in the camp of the ill-informed in   the comments below the question that think that the dielectric is one of the conductors and there is  only one foil; layer.. Show me a journal reference to refute my answer, then I'll take you seriously

Comment: When did I *ever* say anything about the dielectric being a conductor, or that there is only one foil layer in an electrolytic capacitor? All I'm saying is that there are corner cases to everything and that in my *personal* experience, being taught that everything is either in category X or category Y has more than once hindered my understanding of more advanced concepts down the line. It's fine to make simplifications, but *say when you're simplifying*.

Comment: SHow me a journal reference or weblink for electrolytic capacitors made your way

Comment: When did I say *anything* about some way of making electrolytic capacitors? **All** I am talking about is the single overly general statement you made claiming that all materials are either insulators or conductors, which is an *approximation* at best and should be marked as such.

Comment: SHow me a journal reference to support your view.  We all know all capacitors have ESR and leakage R and all resistors and parallel conductors have capacitance.  These are the fundamental truths , not some academic exception that refutes the fundamentals with non-mainstream electronic components. There are also semiconductors doped which have greatest capacitance when the voltage is zero and reduces with increasing negative bias. But this too is irrelevant. All diodes are capacitors when reverse biased. (Variable capacitors)

Comment: What   I am saying is the best model for fundamental material science.  There are always nonlinear properties, thermal, bias, interface ESR, double layer memory effects etc.. Do you understand the double layer effect and why a transient shorted electrolytic including batteries returns with some voltage slowly

Comment: If you read carefully, I can support everything I said. and I am still waiting for your journal reference to refute my answer

Comment: What am I supposed to show a journal article on? [Here's](https://www.memsnet.org/material/titaniumnitridetinbulk/) an academic reference about the high resistivity of bulk titanium nitride at room temperature, and [here's](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1602) a paper talking about the superconductivity of titanium nitride; does that meet your standards? [Here's](https://www.nature.com/subjects/topological-insulators) a page from *Nature* with a definition and list of numerous articles about topological insulators, too.

Comment: How does that refute my answer or be relevant to the question?  Thank you for sharing the esoteric properties of  excitons composed of massive quasiparticles, chiral excitons are the bound states of surface massless electrons and surface massive holes, both subject to strong spin–orbit coupling which locks their spins and momenta into chiral texture.. This appears to be an effect not found in nature and is very challenging to demonstrate in a lab. Thank you for interesting but irrelevant comment to fundamental electronics of dielectric capacitors and fundamental material properties at DC.

Comment: My complaint has nothing to do with capacitors. As I have stated *several times*, my complaint is *solely* about your unconditional statement that a material is either a conductor or an insulator, which is false. It's a fine simplification, particularly in this situation when talking about capacitors, but *it should be stated that it's a simplification*.

Comment: When we examine the nonlinearity of materials and models we call them level 0 ,1 , 2 ,3 ,4 etc. and the domination of certain exceptional properties determines the order we focus on.  This 1st order approximation is bar FAR the best model and likewise an LC component is a 2nd order approximation but with dV/dt and dC/dV we get minor influences so when you say at best a 1st order approximation. I agree. but but far it is this 1st order approximation and any other much higher order effects are not found by your examples. These are molecular pecularities not significant to electronics.

Comment: that is yet..... and perhaps in our next lifetime they may be relevant. Nanotube and nano spiral components are not fundamental properties  (yet) but rather using molecule size parts to replicate exotic shapes of fundamental properties including electroflorescence

Comment: I repeat, I have *personal experience* with statements like this leading to significant difficulty down the line with understanding that things are more complicated than that. *Even introductory texts* should specify that the simplifications they make are simplifications, to avoid others having that same problem.

Comment: @Hearth thankyou for keeping it real , I have added a preface to confine the answer and reflect your wishes.

Comment: @hearth What joke did the  Classical Applied Physicist (Electronics Engineeer )  say to a Quantum Physicist ?  "  Two atoms were walking across a road when one of them said, "I think I lost an electron!" "Really!" the other replied, "Are you sure?"

 "Yes, I 'm absolutely positive.".... Q: Why was Heisenberg such a bad lover?
A: When he got the momentum, he couldn't find the position, and when he found the position, he couldn't muster up the momentum.

Answer (score -1):

1. A standard aluminium electolytic capacitor still has two layers of metal foil acting as the conductors.  If you left out the paper, then they would be pressing against each other.  You need the paper to keep them apart until the oxide later is formed.
2. Then you have a plastic film capacitor.  Polyester film capacitors exist, for example.  They aren't electrolytic and don't behave like electrolytic capacitors.
3. You'd have a wierd capacitor where the insulator was two layers of paper and some vacuum.  It probably wouldn't have a vey high capacitance, though.

Comment: Electrolytic capacitor does NOT have two foil layers. See @user263983 comment for correct answer.

Comment: @Maple Yes, it does have two layers of foil.  Do you think the only conductor for the cathode is a bit of wet paper?

Comment: That is not the point. The second conductor in electrolytic capacitor is always electrolyte, be it solid, liquid or gel. How you make connection from the capacitor lead to the electrolyte is irrelevant. It can be cathode foil, graphite (as in tantalum capacitors) or something else. The paper that you mentioned is not there to separate plates, it is to provide a medium to hold electrolyte "plate". Most important to understand is that electrolyte itself is in **direct contact** with oxide dielectric, despite paper being there.

Comment: What this means is that  **both capacitor plates and dielectric gap between them are on the same side of the paper separator** (when one is used).

Comment: @Maple your comments of using the conductor as an electrolyte breaks the laws of physics. Journal reference proof please

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 where did I say that?! What I said is the opposite - an electrolyte is used as a second conductor (cathode). Note, that "conductor" here means "capacitor plate", as it was used in the answer

Comment: @tonystewartee75 aluminum foil is conductor, electrolyte too. Thin layer of aluminum oxide is insulator. What law of physics you mention? Provide links.

Comment: @Maple your own answer shows and describes an electrolytic capacitor with two foils.

Comment: @DamienD Yes. And not only my answer but also all my comments. But only one of the foils is part of the capacitor, i.e. "a plate". The other one is just a terminal. That is the whole point of a discussion here. We can call the leads of a MOSFET a "gate", "drain" and "source", but we also know that actual gate, drain and source are tiny zones on the semiconductor bead inside.

Answer (score -2):

The paper diffuses the dielectric evenly and provides a consistent gap which defines the breakdown voltage (BDV) which is derated with thermal and tolerance effects for the rated Voltage.

Adding air or vacuum in series with a dielectric constant, Dk=1 compared to a very high Dk electrolyte, puts a tiny capacitance in series, (which dominates the whole C value). It is well known from Arrhenius effects of 50%MTBF every 10'C rise for electrolytics and thus they are rated at max temp for something like 3000 hours or 3kh.  This slowly evaporates the fluid, when heated so capacitors will eventually fail as the capacitance drops replaced by a gas and energy increases in the gap created by a gas  and this in turn causes higher ESR as well as lower C as the electrolyte gradually partially evaporates.   When 2 different C values are in series the smaller C or gap in this example has the most voltage drop. But bubbles are in parallel, so the effect is gradual until the lid bulges out.

Plastic has a lower Dk ~4 which would also lower C but with metallized film also yields a lower ESR making them operate at higher BW. Plastic also has a higher BDV per mm allowing smaller gaps to yield higher C values but still lower C density than electrolytic capacitors.